# Flask Sqlalchemy dynamic updates using variable for keywords

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to dynamically update a database using sqlalchemy.   I need the column name to be dynamically generated based on the string value of file.name.  The location is a string representation of the path of the file and is represented by a variable (location).

I cannot figure out how to dynamically construct a sqlalchemy command that will 1) find the row corresponding to the file_number, 2) locate the appropriate column based on the variable (file.name), and 3) add in the value that is stored in the variable (location) to the database.

```
data_name = str(file.name)
location = str(destination)

db.session.add(Files(**{data_name: location}))
db.session.commit()
```

This works to add the location variable to the right data base location under the right column and column, but does not locate and add it to the correct row (corresponding to the file_number primary key)

I have also tried:

```
row_update = Files.query.filter_by(file_number=f'{file_number}').update().values(text(f'{location}')).where(text(f'Files.{data_name}'))
db.session.execute(row_update)
```

This just creates an error.

**I solved this problem with the below function:**

```
def update_db(name, destination, file_number):
     u = update(Files)
     u = u.values({f'{name}': destination})
     u = u.where(text(f'Files.file_number={file_number}'))  
     db.session.execute(u)
     db.session.commit()
```